# c or c++ type transformation

Tags: c++, c

I have two overload methods in a class, when I call class's method, I pass a argument which can match one of two overload method's argument by upcasting or downcasting. So which one will be really called?

I mean that: `function1(TypeA x)`, `function1(TypeB x)`, when I call `function1(m)`, `m` can upcasting to `TypeA` and `m` can also downcasting to `TypeB`, so which `function1` will be called?

Comment: This has nothing to do with overloading, but `implicit typecasting`...

Comment: What did the book say, exactly?

Comment: are you talking about typecasting??

Comment: it looks like examples of implicit and explicit type conversions.

Comment: I read the overload function chapter of c++ primer.Can you tell me the difference about above two groups of transformation ?

Comment: argument matching related to my question

Comment: You have shown no methods in your code above, so it's difficult to know what you're talking about...

Comment: do you want to know how calls are made, depending on arguments, to the overloaded function?

Comment: Please some one help me slove my doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the question changed, so i refer version 4 that really asks about up/downcasting in contrast to older revs that were more about type conversions.

if you assume:

```
class A{};
class B: public A{};
class C: public B{};

void function(const A&);
void function(const C&);
```

and you have an

```
C c;
const A& a = c;
const B& b = c;
```

so that in all cases it references the same object and you call and get the following

```
function(a);  // --> function(const A&);
function(b);  // --> function(const A&);
function(c);  // --> function(const C&);
```

why? because the compiler can not know (actually in this simple version it can - but normally that is not the case) the runtime type of the base class reference object at compiletime. So it only can choose between safe alternatives.

upcasting is always possible due to that it is safe because the given object always has all features of its base class. downcasting should be avoided and only be done with dynamic casts.

refer: http://codepad.org/IeYK1fLC

Answer (score 2):

In the first example floating point precision is added to 1 (I believe it's called "integral promotion").

In the second example the fractional part is truncated in order to cast to the destination type implicitly. This is what C++ standard draft states on this (n3242 4.9-1):

> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an
>   integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part
>   is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot
>   be represented in the destination type.[Note: If the destination type is bool, see 4.12. —end note]